# @tanstack/react-query: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

Premise: i got this error only on production (next.js) and not always, just sometimes.

I use the package @tanstack/react-query in my next.js project. Sometimes in production, out of nowhere, i got the issue

> No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one

and the app breaks.
This is my implementation

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    const [queryClient] = useState(() => new QueryClient(options));

    return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <ErrorBoundary>
                <HydrationBoundary state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
                    <Providers pageProps={pageProps}>
                        <Component {...pageProps} />
                    </Providers>
                </HydrationBoundary>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </QueryClientProvider>
    );
}
```

Note that in the same project i use another package, wagmi, which uses @tanstack/react-query too but of a different version (i use 5.0.0, they use 4.3.2).

I appreciate any tips on how to solve this.

Comment: Show your package.json and your imports. This GitHub issue seems to suggest it’s common when people accidentally have react query and tanstack/query installed and aren’t using all the same imports https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/3069#issuecomment-1518582538.

Comment: @AdamJenkins i only have "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.15.5" in my package.json

Comment: I missed the part about the mismatched packages, you do indeed have 2 versions because of the other dependency. Suggestion is to downgrade yours to 4.x.

Comment: @AdamJenkins i already tried to use the version 4.x, but the error happens still. It seems that having the same version twice can cause problem too.

Comment: no it won’t. If you are using the same version as your dependency, then they’ll only be one version in node modules. Run [npm ls](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ls) on tanstack query after you do it to confirm you only have one version. A good idea is to blow away your node modules and delete your next build cache as well before you do it.

Comment: @AdamJenkins when i run npm ls it only shows me @tanstack/react-query@5.15.5

Answer (score 0):

if wagmi has a dependency on tanstack-query v4, you also need to use tanstack-query v4. Using a different version means you have multiple versions of react-query installed, which means the context Provider created from the v5 import will not be "visible" to the consumers that use the `useQuery` hook from v4.